# slow cuda computing time

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, cuda

Hello I am a beginner in cuda programming. this my code.

```
#include "book.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cuda.h> 
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>
#define pop 1000
#define gen 1000
#define p gen*pop

using namespace std;

//random generator di GPU
__device__ float generate( curandState *globalState, int i) 
{
    //int ind = threadIdx.x;
    curandState localState = globalState[i];
    float RANDOM = curand_uniform( &localState );
    globalState[i] = localState;
    return RANDOM;
}

__global__ void setup_kernel ( curandState * state, unsigned long seed )
{
    int id = threadIdx.x;
    curand_init ( seed, id, 0, &state[id] );
}
__global__ void crossover(int *child, int *parent, curandState* globalState, int *x, int *y)
{
    int tid=(blockIdx.x*blockDim.x)+threadIdx.x;
    int distance1,distance2;
    int tmp;
    if(tid<pop-1)
    {

        for(int j=0;j<gen;j++)
        {

            if (j == 0)
            {
                child[(tid*gen)+j]= generate(globalState,tid) * gen;//ini hassilnya tdak random bagus
            }
            else
            {

                distance1=sqrt((float)( pow ((double)(x[parent[(tid*gen)+j]]-x[child[(tid*gen)+(j-1)]]),2.0)+pow((double)(y[parent[(tid*gen)+j]]-y[child[(tid*gen)+(j-1)]]),2.0)));
                distance2=sqrt((float)( pow ((double)(x[parent[((tid+1)*gen)+j]]-x[child[(tid*gen)+(j-1)]]),2.0)+pow((double)(y[parent[((tid+1)*gen)+j]]-y[child[(tid*gen)+(j-1)]]),2.0)));             
                //anak[(tid*gen)+j]=tid;//thread dimana komputasi jalan
                if (distance1<distance2)
                {
                    tmp=parent[(tid*gen)+j];
                }

                tmp=parent[((tid+1)*gen)+j];

                bool same;
                do
                {
                    same=false;
                    for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
                    {
                        if (child[(tid*gen)+i] == tmp)
                        {
                            same=true;
                            tmp=generate(globalState, tid)*gen ;
                        }
                    }child[(tid*gen)+j]=tmp;
                }while(same);

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int j=0;j<gen;j++)
        {
            if (j == 0)
            {
                child[(tid*gen)+j]= generate(globalState,tid) * gen;
            }
            else
            {
                distance1=sqrt((float)(pow((double)(x[parent[(tid*gen)+j]]-x[child[(tid*gen)+(j-1)]]),2.0))+pow((double)(y[parent[(tid*gen)+j]]-y[child[(tid*gen)+(j-1)]]),2.0));
                distance2=sqrt((float)(pow((double)(x[parent[j]]-x[child[(tid*gen)+(j-1)]]),2.0))+pow((double)(y[parent[j]]-y[child[(tid*gen)+(j-1)]]),2.0));

                if (distance1<distance2)
                {
                    tmp=parent[(tid*gen)+j];
                }

                tmp=parent[j];

                bool samme;
                do
                {
                    samme=false;
                    for(int i=0;i<j;i++)
                    {
                        if (child[(tid*gen)+i] == tmp)
                        {
                            samme=true;
                            tmp=generate(globalState, tid)*gen ;
                        }
                    }child[(tid*gen)+j]=tmp;
                }while(samme);

            }
        }

    }
}
int main (void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    float time1;
    int x[gen],y[gen];
    int *dev_x,*dev_y;
    double MAX = 100.;
    int* parent=new int [p];
    int* child=new int [p];
    int *dev_parent;
    int *dev_child;
    for (int i=0;i<gen;i++)
    {
        float unirand = ((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX);
         x[i] = MAX*unirand;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<gen;i++)
    {
        float unirand = ((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX);
        y[i] = MAX*unirand;
    }
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_x, gen * sizeof(int) ) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_y, gen * sizeof(int) ) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( dev_x, x, gen * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( dev_y, y, gen * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );
    bool check;
    for (int i=0;i<pop;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<gen;j++)
        {
            do
            {
                check = false;
                parent[ ((i*gen)+j) ] = rand()%gen;
                for (int k=0;k<j;k++)
                {
                    if (parent[ ((i*gen)+j) ] == parent[ ((i*gen)+k) ])
                    {
                        check = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            while (check);

        }
    }
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_parent, p * sizeof(int) ) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_child, p * sizeof(int) ) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy (dev_parent, parent, p * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );

    curandState* devStates;
    HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc ( &devStates, pop * sizeof( curandState ) ));
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventCreate(&start) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventCreate(&stop) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventRecord(start, 0) );
    setup_kernel <<< pop, 1 >>> ( devStates, unsigned(time(NULL)) );
    crossover<<<pop, 1>>>(dev_child,dev_parent,devStates,dev_x,dev_y);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventRecord(stop, 0) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventSynchronize(stop) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaEventElapsedTime(&time1, start, stop) );
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy ( child, dev_child, p * sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ) );
    printf("crossover:  %3.1f ms \n", time1);
    cudaFree( dev_child );
    cudaFree( dev_parent );
    cudaFree( devStates );
    cudaFree( dev_x );
    cudaFree( dev_y );
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

execution time is 17943 ms in cuda. please help me to be faster. And sometimes if  gen > 500 n pop > 500 error in line cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost. thankyou

Comment: Two very loud performance alarm bells: (i) you're using double precision in your distance calculations (why ?) and (ii) you're calling `pow` just to square a value (again, why ?).

Comment: thank you for you answer n question. (i)i not using double precision for distance.  i am using int (int distance1,int distance 2). (ii) because i am using euclidean formula.

Comment: You're casting ints to doubles just to square them (by calling pow) and then converting back to int again - this is insane, when all you need is one int multliply.

Answer (score 4):

There will probably be many ways you can improve performance, but I expect the largest jump to come from fixing your launch configuration. The section `<<< pop, 1 >>>` tells the GPU that you have `pop` blocks, each with one thread. For a GPU kernel to be efficient you need many blocks, each with many threads.

While optimal block sizes varies on a case-by-case basis, for all current GPUs a block size which is a multiple of 128 will often be most efficient. That is, you'll want to call your kernels with something like `<<< x, 128 >>>` or `<<< y, 256 >>>`. The total number of threads you will be launching here is x*128, or y*256, and you'll want to calculate x or y accordingly. Note: just as having one thread per block is inefficient, having one block per grid is inefficient. You typically want to have 50+ blocks launched.

Of course, to achieve the above you will need many more elements than you are currently working on. 1000-way parallelism just isn't enough for anything but the cheapest of current GPUs.